# Azure Function - Trigger Queue For Debug

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I have an azure function that has a QueueTrigger. This QueueTrigger is the method I would like to debug against.

I am able to start debugging my function via f5, and in the function core tools it processes until it displays message:

```
Host lock lease acquired by instance ID ''.
```

I am able to hit breakpoints that are within overriden Configuration in Startup without issue. I am now interested in triggering the QueueTrigger. I start azurrite and recieve:

```
Azurite Blob service is starting at http://127.0.0.1:10000
Azurite Blob service is successfully listening at http://127.0.0.1:10000
Azurite Queue service is starting at http://127.0.0.1:10001
Azurite Queue service is successfully listening at http://127.0.0.1:10001
Azurite Table service is starting at http://127.0.0.1:10002
Azurite Table service is successfully listening at http://127.0.0.1:10002
127.0.0.1 - - [25/Jan/2024:22:50:20 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 400
```

I am now lost however. How do I call my specific Queue trigger? I see it listed under the Azure Core Functions cmd prompt, however not sure how to invoke it.

Comment: Get Azure Storage explorer and drop a message on the local queue. There is documentation on this … https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-explorer-emulators

Comment: @user3010406 is it a service bus queue trigger or storgae Queue trigger

Comment: @user3010406 which programing language you are using?

Comment: @VivekVaibhavShandilya looks like azurite (supported in Node.js)

Answer (score 1):

To invoke a queue trigger from a local emulator using Azurite, use `Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer`. Download it from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/vs-azure-tools-storage-manage-with-storage-explorer?tabs=windows#download-and-install).

- Open `Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer`.
- Select your storage account from **`Emulator & Attached -> Storage Accounts -> Emulator - Default Ports -> Queues -> <QueueName>`**.
- Run your Queue trigger.
- Click on `Add` to add a message to the Queue and press `OK`.

[image]

My Queue Trigger code in Python:

**`__init__.py`:**

```py
import logging

from azure.functions import QueueMessage

def main(msg: QueueMessage) -> None:
    logging.info('Python queue trigger function processed a queue item: %s',
                 msg.get_body().decode('utf-8'))
```

**`function.json`:**

```json
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "msg",
      "type": "queueTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "queueName": "test",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
    }
  ]
}
```

**`OUTPUT`:**

```
Functions:

        QueueTrigger1: queueTrigger

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-01-31T11:10:43.398Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000AAE5F384'.
[2024-01-31T11:10:51.435Z] Executing 'Functions.QueueTrigger1' (Reason='New queue message detected on 'test'.', Id=6ca1b822-9f16-457a-9179-c01ae9a1be4d)
[2024-01-31T11:10:51.442Z] Trigger Details: MessageId: 7e5d0e29-16e2-4904-bd0e-3b222132d8c6, DequeueCount: 1, InsertedOn: 2024-01-31T11:10:49.000+00:00
[2024-01-31T11:10:51.663Z] Python queue trigger function processed a queue item: Hi Vivek, This message is from Local Emulator
[2024-01-31T11:10:51.745Z] Executed 'Functions.QueueTrigger1' (Succeeded, Id=6ca1b822-9f16-457a-9179-c01ae9a1be4d, Duration=357ms)
```

[image]